# Statiscal Distance Properties

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, metric-spaces

Please anyone could give me any idea of how prove the following property of statistical distance:

$d(AB,CD)\leq d(A,C)+d(B,D)$

Remenber that:

$(X,d)$---> Metric Space

$d:X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$

$d(A,B)=P(A\bigtriangleup B)=P((A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A) )$

see more in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance)

Comment: What is $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$? Also, what are the properties of a "statistical distance"? The wiki page doesn't help me.

Comment: @user2875124 A, B, C, and D are events and the distance is between events

Comment: Ok, then what do you mean by the product of two events? Is it their intersection?

Comment: @user2875124 Yes, it is their intersection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one proof:

First a guide to notation:

$AB=A\cap B$

$A+B=A\cup B$

$\overline{A}=A^c$

Now my proof:

$d(A,C)=d(A\overline{C})+d(C\overline{A})$

$d(B,D)=d(B\overline{D})+d(D\overline{B})$

$d(AB,CD)=d(AB\overline{(CD)})+d(CD\overline{(AB)})=d(AB(\overline{C}+\overline{D}))+d(CD(\overline{A}+\overline{B}))=d((AB\overline{C})+(AB\overline{D}))+d((CD\overline{A})+(CD\overline{B}))=d(AB\overline{C})+d(AB\overline{D})-d(AB\overline{C}\overline{D})+d(CD\overline{A})+d(CD\overline{B})-d(CD\overline{A}\overline{B})$

see that:

$d(AB\overline{C})\leq d(A\overline{C})$

$d(AB\overline{D})\leq d(B\overline{D})$

$d(CD\overline{A}) \leq d(C\overline{A})$

$d(CD\overline{B}) \leq d(D\overline{B})$

from wich we deduce that

$d(AB\overline{C})+d(AB\overline{D})+d(CD\overline{A})+d(CD\overline{B})\leq d(A\overline{C})+d(B\overline{D})+d(C\overline{A})+d(D\overline{B})=d(A,C)+d(B,D)$

or better:

$d(AB\overline{C})+d(AB\overline{D})-d(AB\overline{C}\overline{D})+d(CD\overline{A})+d(CD\overline{B})-d(CD\overline{A}\overline{B})\leq d(A,C)+d(B,D)$

This leads us:

$d(AB,CD)\leq d(A,C)+d(B,D)$